# Problem/Error in Biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I made a book on Overleaf, where the project had no errors. But now I want to open this project in TexStudio, but I can't compile the project because it gives me the following error: Package biblatex Error: File 'relatorio.bbl' not created by biblatex.
In the compilation options it is txs:///bibtex | txs:///pdflatex | txs:///bibtex.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You need to tell your editor chain to use `biber` not `bibtex`. `biber` is presumably what OverLeaf is using behind the scences.

Comment: In TeXStudio >> Options >> Configure TeXStudio >> Build you can specify the default bibliography tool.

Comment: You need to configure your editor to run Biber instead of BibTeX as daleif says. (Overleaf uses the awesome `latexmk` to automate compilation for you. Locally you'll most likely have to tell your editor what to do,) Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864. Do note that Overleaf is very good at hiding errors from users, so it could be that you still get errors locally that you don't see on Overleaf.

Comment: I voted to close this question as a duplicate of our go-to "configure the editor for Biber" question, since that is the most likely cause of the issue given the current state of the question. If you tried that and it did not work for you, I suggest you ask a new question explaining in more detail what you did and how it did not work for you.